# UIView animation transition between views

Tags: iphone, objective-c, animation, uiview

I need to make an animation that will come in from the right, displaying the new view.

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
        [UIView setAnimationCurve:UIViewAnimationCurveEaseInOut];
        [UIView setAnimationDelay:.5f];
        [UIView setAnimationDuration:0.5f];


// display view controller
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

What should I add here??

Comment: How can a make another view slide in from the right???!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you have navigationController then use

```
NextViewcontroller *nextView = [NextViewcontroller alloc]initWithNibName@"NextViewcontroller"
bundle:nil];

[self.navigationController pushViewcontroller:nextView animated:YES];

[nextView release];
```

Comment: but if I don't?) I have view-based application)

Answer (score 0):

How about adding the view as a subView to your current view, then set its place to be outside the current visible area. After which you set your animation  to change your subViews position to overlap the current view.